# MSBee and its use

Tags: asp.net, msbuild, msbee

What exactly is MSBee? How should I use it in addition to MSBuild to build web applications which are created in Visual Studio .NET 2003 and that target .NET Framework 1.1?

Answer (score 4):

> MSBuild Extras – Toolkit for .NET 1.1
>   “MSBee” is an addition to MSBuild that
>   allows developers to build managed
>   applications using Visual Studio 2005
>   projects that target .NET 1.1.

Take a look at the codeplex page:

http://www.codeplex.com/wikipage?ProjectName=MSBee

Also, look into upgrading the version of .NET/VS you are using.  You're due...